# How to add decode but also have count, group by and order by - not a group by expression

Tags: oracle, group-by, decode, sql-order-by

I'm rather new to Oracle. I'm trying to do a count of ports for a vendor/model.  However, I only want ones with port_addr_status of 3 or 4.  For some reason, I'm getting error

> **ORA-00979** not a group by expression

This is what I have so far.  It works without the decode part, but I don't think the part with pi.port_addr.status in ('3','4') works without it. I'm open to working around that issue as well.

```
select 
   count(pi.port) as cnt, d.VENDOR, trim(d.model) as model, 
   decode(pi.PORT_ADDR_STATUS, '1', 'Unassigned', '2','Pending','3','In Service', 
                               '4','Pending Disco', '5','Trouble', '6','Reserved', 
                               '7','Reserved Capacity', pi.PORT_ADDR_STATUS)
from
   table1 pi,
   table2 d,
   table3 c
where
   pi.id = d.id and
   pi.circuit_id = c.circuit_id 
   and pi.port_addr_status in ('3','4')
   and (d.dslam_type_desc not in ('AGGREGATOR') or d.dslam_type_desc is null)
   and d.DSLAM not like '%@%' 
group by 
       d.VENDOR, d.model --, trim(d.model), pi.RACK, pi.SHELF, pi.SLOT, pi.PORT, pi.BROADBAND_CIRCUIT_ID, d.DSLAM, 
order by
       d.VENDOR asc, cnt desc
```

This is sample output:

```
1031    Adtran  TA5000
10      Adtran  TA1248V
3       Adtran  TA1248
```

Comment: Adding a sample result set of what you want the output to be would help. If we go with what you said exactly - "I'm trying to do a count of ports for a vendor/model." then the answer is "remove the decode entirely". If you really want a count by vendor/model/port type, then add the port type to your group by.

Comment: @dandarc - I added sample output. I need the decode.  Otherwise I will get a count that includes 'Unassigned', etc.

Comment: see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the decoded port type is not required in your output, just remove it from the select list. Group By should include everything in the select list except the aggregate functions. The below query should do the job:

```
select 
   count(pi.port) as cnt, d.VENDOR, trim(d.model) as model
from
   table1 pi,
   table2 d,
   table3 c
where
   pi.id = d.id and
   pi.circuit_id = c.circuit_id 
   and pi.port_addr_status in ('3','4')
   and (d.dslam_type_desc not in ('AGGREGATOR') or d.dslam_type_desc is null)
   and d.DSLAM not like '%@%' 
group by 
       d.VENDOR, trim(d.model)
order by
       d.VENDOR asc, cnt desc
```

Note that the filter down to specific port types is achieved here:

```
and pi.port_addr_status in ('3','4')
```

in the where clause - the decode statement in your original query did nothing to solve your requirements and was the direct cause of the error. In a basic aggregate query like this, group by should have every item that is in the select list that is not an aggregate function.

Comment: Isn't the decode part what pi.port_addr_status in ('3','4') uses to know that it just needs 'In Service' and 'Pending Disco' ones?

Comment: No - the decode in your original query would have been another column in your result set that instead of "3" and "4" would have "In Service" and "Pending Disco" respectively. Your sample results do not have that column, therefore you don't need it in your select list. For SQL basics: https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_introduction. For what decode specifically does: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm

Comment: put another way - "and pi.port_addr_status in ('3','4')" in the where clause does the filtering - you don't need a decode here for any reason - you're not displaying the decoded values, you know what codes to look for - no reason to use decode anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `decode` statement in the select list with an aggregation function preferably `max` as

`max( decode(pi.PORT_ADDR_STATUS, '1', 'Unassigned', '2','Pending', .... )`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting that error is:

1. when using a GROUP BY clause you are asking the DBMS to give you a single row corresponding to your GROUP BY list
2. in your case, you are asking for one row per (Vendor, Model) combination
3. since each of these rows represents possibly many "underlying" rows (say, e.g. 5 rows for Vendor=A and Model=B), the only other fields you can have in the select list must be aggregates (that's why the "count" field works, it counts the rows, i.e. it can take many row values and return a single value)
4. the DECODE function is not an aggregate function - it can't "collapse" multiple values into one value (like, say, MAX() can)

It looks to me as if your DECODE function returns strings, so I recommend you aggregate the strings with the LISTAGG function (so if your 5 rows have values of 'asdf', 'fdsa', 'qwer', 'rewq', and 'zxcv' the LISTAGG function would return a single string: 'asdf,fdsa,qwer,rewq,zxcv')

So you would replace your DECODE(...) call with, e.g. LISTAGG(DECODE(...), ',')

Reference for LISTAGG function: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030